# Problema con arreglos en java

Tags: java

Resulta que tengo las siguientes clases:

```
public class Factura4  {
 double totalZapatos;
 double totalZapatosNacional;
 double totalZapatosArtesanal;
 Zapatos[] lista= new Zapatos[5];
 Zapatos zap=new Zapatos();
 ZapatosNacional zapna=new ZapatosNacional();
 ZapatosArtesanal zapar=new ZapatosArtesanal();
 // Constructores
 public Factura4(double totalZapatos, double totalZapatosNacional, double totalZapatosArtesanal){
        this.totalZapatos = totalZapatos;
        this.totalZapatosNacional = totalZapatosNacional;
        this.totalZapatosArtesanal = totalZapatosArtesanal;
 }

    Factura4(Zapatos[] zapatos) {
        
    }

    // Metodos
    public void mostrarTotales() {
        // Calculo de totales
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            lista[i]=new Zapatos(zap.getMarca(),zap.getTipo_material(),zap.getPrecioBase());
            lista[i]=new ZapatosNacional(zapna.getRegion());
            lista[i]=new ZapatosArtesanal(zapar.getTamaño());
        }
        for(int i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
            totalZapatosNacional=lista[i].calcularPrecio()+zapna.calcularPrecio();
            totalZapatosArtesanal=zapar.calcularPrecio();
            totalZapatos=totalZapatosNacional+totalZapatosArtesanal+lista[i].calcularPrecio();
        }
        System.out.println("El precio total de los zapatos es de " + totalZapatos);
        System.out.println("La suma del precio de los ZapatosNacional es de " + totalZapatosNacional);
        System.out.print("La suma del precio de los ZapatosArtensal es de " + totalZapatosArtesanal);
    }
    
}

public class Zapatos {
 
 private final static String MARCA="Arturo";
 private final static String TIPO_MATERIAL ="Cuero";
 private final static int PRECIO_BASE=10000;

 private String marca=MARCA;
 private String tipo_material=TIPO_MATERIAL;
 private int precioBase=PRECIO_BASE;
 private double precioFinal;

    public Zapatos(String marca, String tipo_material, int precioBase) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.tipo_material = tipo_material;
        this.precioBase = precioBase;
    }

    Zapatos() {
        
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getTipo_material() {
        return tipo_material;
    }

    public void setTipo_material(String tipo_material) {
        this.tipo_material = tipo_material;
    }

    public int getPrecioBase() {
        return precioBase;
    }

    public void setPrecioBase(int precioBase) {
        this.precioBase = precioBase;
    }

    public static String getMARCA() {
        return MARCA;
    }

    public static String getTIPO_MATERIAL() {
        return TIPO_MATERIAL;
    }

    public static int getPRECIO_BASE() {
        return PRECIO_BASE;
    }
  
    
 
 public double calcularPrecio(){
     if(marca=="Arturo"){
         precioBase=precioBase+((precioBase*75)/100);
         
     }
     else{
         precioBase=precioBase+((precioBase*20)/100);
     }
     if(tipo_material=="Cuero"){
         if(precioBase>=5000){
            precioBase=precioBase-5000;
         }
     }
     else{
         if(precioBase>=500&&precioBase<5000){
            precioBase=precioBase-500;
         }
     }
    precioFinal=precioBase;
 return precioFinal;
 }
 
 public double getPrecioFinal() {
        return precioFinal;
    }

    public void setPrecioFinal(double precioFinal) {
        this.precioFinal = precioFinal;
    }

}

public class ZapatosNacional extends Zapatos {
    // Constantes
 private final static String REGION="Cundinamarca";
 // Atributos
 private String region=REGION;
 Zapatos zapato=new Zapatos();
 // Constructores

    public ZapatosNacional(String region, String marca, String tipo_material, int precioBase) {
        super(marca, tipo_material, precioBase);
        this.region = region;
    }

    public ZapatosNacional(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    ZapatosNacional() {
        
    }

    public static String getREGION() {
        return REGION;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    
  
 // Metodos
@Override
 public double calcularPrecio(){
     double precioba=zapato.getPrecioFinal();
     if(region=="Cundinamarca"){
        precioba=precioba+10000;
     }
 // Calculos
 double precioFinal=precioba;
 return precioFinal;
 }
 
}

public class ZapatosArtesanal extends Zapatos {
    
 private final static int TAMAÑO = 40;

 private int tamaño=TAMAÑO;

 Zapatos zapato=new Zapatos();

    public ZapatosArtesanal(int tamaño, String marca, String tipo_material, int precioBase) {
        super(marca, tipo_material, precioBase);
        this.tamaño = tamaño;
    }

    public ZapatosArtesanal(int tamaño) {
        this.tamaño = tamaño;
    }

    ZapatosArtesanal() {
        
    }

    public static int getTAMAÑO() {
        return TAMAÑO;
    }

    public int getTamaño() {
        return tamaño;
    }

    
 
@Override
 public double calcularPrecio(){
     double precio=this.getPrecioFinal();
     if(tamaño<40){
         precio=precio+10000;
     }
     else{
         precio=precio+4500;
     }
    double precioFinal=precio;
 return precioFinal;
 }
 
}

public class App {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
// Caso de Prueba 1
 Zapatos zapatos[]=new Zapatos[5];
 zapatos[0]=new Zapatos("Arturo", "Cuero", 5000);
 zapatos[1]=new ZapatosNacional("Valle");
 zapatos[2]=new ZapatosArtesanal(42);
 zapatos[3]=new Zapatos();
 zapatos[4]=new ZapatosNacional("Cundinamarca");
 Factura4 solucion = new Factura4(zapatos);
 solucion.mostrarTotales(); 
 }
}
```

Y debo de lograr que segun las condiciones de los metodos en las clases de zapatos, me de un total para cada clase. ZapatosNacional y ZapatosArtesanal son clases hijas de la superclase Zapatos y en la clase factura4 se recibe una lista de zapatos con las cuales se debe de hacer los calculos. Tomando como ejemplo el caso de prueba en la clase App, El total zapatos deberia dar 68250.0, el total zapatosnacional 35000.0 y  zapatos artesanal 17000.0, pero me he dado cuenta que el programa no toma los valores del arreglo en la clase App por lo que no importa si se cambian valores en esta, siempre da los mismos resultados y ademas ni siquiera hace bien los calculos.

Que estoy haciendo mal? Estoy a punto de colapsar
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor intenta no poner tanto código (haz incluido 235 líneas). Te recomiendo que leas [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: La clase `Factura4` nunca usa los valores del arreglo que le pasas por constructor ya que dicho constructor tiene el cuerpo vacío: `Factura4(Zapatos[] zapatos) {
 
}`

Comment: Lamento el codigo tan largo, y gracias. Entonces en el constructor debo poner los atributos de las diferentes clases de zapatos o como?

Comment: Yo no veo incremento en tus totales. Deberías declarar una variable por fuera de los bucles e ir sumando a esa variable dentro de los bucles `for` para tener los totales correctos al final de los bucles.